# Vb.net ADODB connection to Share Point doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, ado, adodb

In vb.net I am  trying to open connection string to Share Point , the code sticks at `cnt.Open` command below  and keeps running forever but no error shown  , I used the same syntax before with VBA and it worked ,

```
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
cnt.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=Location;LIST=LISTNAME; ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot New on your connection.

```
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
cnt.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=Location;LIST=LISTNAME; ")
```

Comment: Thanks Brian , I already have this in another line , and its still not working , just running without stop

Comment: Well, then I suspect the connection string is not correct.  I would recommend verifying it and perhaps removing the trailing space.

Comment: In this portion of the connection string "DATABASE=Location;LIST=LISTNAME" what is Location and LISTNAME?  Are they a variable containing the required data?

Comment: No I put the value directly I just  replaced it with these names for simplicity , this syntax is working in vba and I copied it exactly as it is